# Is this a tongue-in-cheek wit: "donner une carte colorée à Trump"?

Tags: sens

> Les Japonais ont **donné une carte colorée** à Trump pour l’aider à comprendre leurs investissements aux USA.

I wonder if this expression (apparently meaning "give *limited* free rein to Trump") is commonly recognised as a tongue-in-cheek variant of "**donner carte blanche** à Trump"?

I also notice the addition of the indefinite article: "donner **une** carte colorée à Trump".

Comment: When I read [the article](http://www.slate.fr/story/179106/japonais-donne-carte-coloree-trump-aider-comprendre-investissements-usa) I see no metaphorical meaning in this expression. Trump was given a colourful map to help him understand the Japanese investments in the US.  Compare to headline in [the Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/trump-japan-map-chart-g20-shinzo-abe-investment-a8980891.html) relating same invent. And both articles show the map Shinzo Abe gave Trump, it is, indeed, colourful.

Comment: @Laure Yes, literally colourful, too. That said, seeing as how they used this phrasing in the headline, doesn't it carry more than a literal meaning?

Comment: It doesn't to me, it  says no more than the headline in the *Independent*. And I know no French  idiom including *carte colorée*.

Comment: That metaphorical interpretation also doesn't really make any sense in this context. Limited rein to do what? Understand their US investments?

Comment: @temporary_user_name If you go by this French sentence alone, it isn't as much of a stretch as you make it out to be to interpret it the way I did: "*Japan lets Trump handle the situation **the way he sees fit** – **albeit partially** – so that he will come to take stock of Japan's overall contribution (from a wider perspective)*".

Comment: The only tongue-in-cheek wit in this *carte colorée* allusion is the reference to Juncker having used ["brightly coloured flash cards to explain international trade to Trump](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/trump-juncker-trade-us-eu-trade-tariffs-white-house-meeting-flashcards-a8467051.html). The *Slate* article does allude to this episode and links to it.

Comment: The original article in the Independent is tongue-in-cheek - *colourful* doesn't just mean *coloré*, it means something like *tout en couleurs* i.e. appealing to children. The overall tone of the original comes across in the Slate article, I would say. FWIW I don't think *donné une carte colorée* is tongue-in-cheek if we are talking about the choice of words, but then the only reason to mention that the chart was in colour is to get across that the Japanese were treating Trump like a child - i.e. to poke fun.

Answer (score 1):

You might be reading too much into the *carte colorée*.  It doesn't make me think of *donner carte blanche*.  It would be useful if you could give us a bit more information about the quotation, especially where it's taken from. With the little you provide, it's difficult to see if the author is dissing Trump by suggesting he's in need of a coloured table to understand things.

Comment: The link to the article was given in my comment above, and I also link to the original article in the Independent.

Comment: Thank you, I'd missed it.  Same old lazy journalism in French or in English.

Comment: I just read again the Slate article and found a nice and basic spelling mistake : "Il lui a donné une carte du pays simple et coloré".  What a joke!

Answer (score 1):

Oui mais pas dans le sens de « donner carte blanche » ([contexte](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/is-this-a-tongue-in-cheek-wit-donner-une-carte-color%C3%A9e-%C3%A0-trump#comment74469_37302)) ; cette association est à mon avis invraisemblable. En anglais on avait *colorful map* (*The Independent* : « Japan gives Trump colourful map to help him understand its investment in US ; ‘Kudos to Japan, they figured out how best to interact with a toddler. So sad’ » ; certaines sources ont *chart*) et l'article de *Slate* est semble-t-il une traduction et *coloré* [traduit](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/colorful/571137#644094) *colorful*. Même si l'expression [*carte blanche*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carte_blanche) existe (par emprunt au français) en langue anglaise il est impossible à mon avis qu'on ait associé *map* à *carte (blanche)* dans la langue originale. Je trouve que *carte en couleur* aurait été plus usuel. Mais on semble jouer la carte de la référence à l'enfant impressionné par les couleurs vives autant que celle de la personne dont il faut capter l'attention déficiente. En d'autres mots il fallait lui [*faire un dessin*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_un_dessin).

D'ailleurs le thème de la couleur et du dessin suscite la réflexion des commentateurs (« Commenters pointed out how similar it was to a child’s picture book and asked whether it came with crayons », The Independent ; « Selon l’Independent, des commentateurs un brin sarcastique ont demandé si le tout était fourni avec des crayons de couleur » *Slate*, en passant il y a des fautes d'orthographe dans l'article de *Slate*). La référence est celle de l'[*album à colorier*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/album/2063#645003).

Le tout connote de l'imbécilité et de la faible estime qu'on a du personnage dont on associe malheureusement les caractéristiques, comme l'intellect et le niveau d'attention, à celles d'un tout petit, d'un enfant en bas âge, salissant la notion à mon avis. Mais ça ne saurait jamais autant le faire que les propos que cet homme a tenus dans sa vie au sujet d'un nombre incalculable de personnes, de groupes ou de pays ainsi qu'au cours de son mandat dont un souhaite ardemment la fin. C'est de bonne guerre.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Toi aussi semble-t-il tu as besoin de majuscules et du caractère gras pour t'exprimer. Je n'en ai pas besoin pour comprendre. Malheureusement pour toi le site ne permet pas que je sache de changer la couleur du texte, je t'écrirais quelque chose de plus coloré. Mais c'est de bonne guerre.

Answer (score -1):

This is, no doubt, aimed at rhyming with the expression "donner carte blanche" and the verb "donner", which is remarkable for the lack of specificity it shows, for its common place connotations, has been chosen expressly with that in mind; normally, a verbe such as "fournir", or "remettre", or an expression such as "joindre  à leurs explications une carte coloriée" would have been more proper than this word connoting essentially the idea of a gift or nothing in particular (as when handing sth to someone you say "donner qqc à qqn").The idea of colored chart is by the way, overplayed, the chart is of a uniform light blue colour (shown below).

[image]

I've never heard or read any figurative expression similar to "laisser carte blanche" using the term "carte colorée".

Nevertheless, the idea is very probably gratuitous,  as is all the hulaballoo about Trump being the only politician on the planet having to rely on charts and maps for acquiring and retaining some knowledge about complex global and regional situations. There is no context for the Japanese delegating decision power to American administration in matters of trade: all decisions in that domain are the product of bilateral arrangements or unilateral impositions, except possibly on the level of very limited facets of the business, but that's out of the question here.

Comment: It is not gratuitous at all. As said in the article (the article in *The Independent* as well as the translation on *Slate.fr*) it is an allusion to Juncker using  ‘brightly coloured, simple flashcards’ to explain trade to Trump.

Comment: @Laure No, that's not what I mean; what's gratuitous is the proximity with "donner carte blanche", which has been sought by choosing the verb "donner" instead of  a term not as colloquial and better suited to the level of language expected.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Qu'est-ce que l'on fait alors de l'irrépressible soupçon du OP ?

Comment: @suiiurisesse Ça, c'est à peu près ce que je dis: il n'est pas question de "carte blanche", mais on a l'impression que la traduction ne fait rien pour annuler des allusions vagues à cette idée et cela ce n'est pas exactement ce que l'on appelle de la rédaction judicieuse. (En passant, L'Ac. déconseille cette locution, "au final', elle ne semble pas relever d'une structure réelle.)

Comment: Je comprends. Je ne vois aucune allusion, même vague. La locution _donner carte blanche_ ne contient aucun déterminant (_une_). _Donner une carte blanche et bleue_  ou _donner carte colorée_ aurait été une allusion. Bof, c'est vraiment peu intéressant d'en débattre, c'est sujet à opinion. Le _au final_ j'ai appris ça sur le site, je n'utilise pas ça dans mon sociolecte, où je dirais _finalement_. De toutes façons je ne suis pas toujours les conseils de l'Académie.